# Find the radius of convergence for this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

Let $[a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n]$ be the least common multiple of numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. Then what should the radius of convergence be for the following series:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{[1,2,...,n]}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), the [Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) has the asymptotic $\psi(n) = n(1+o(1))$ , which tells that $[1, 2, \ldots, n] = \exp(\psi(n)) = \exp(n(1+o(1))$. Therefore, $[1, 2, \ldots, n]^{1/n} = \mathrm e+o(1)$, and hence the radius of convergence is $\mathrm e$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A003418) says $[1,2,...,n]$ goes asymptotically as $\exp(n)$